# How to list the published container images in the Google Container Registry using gcloud or another CLI

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Is there a `gcloud` API or other command line interface (CLI) to access the list of published container images in the private Google Container Registry? (That is the container registry inside a Google Cloud Platform project)

`gcloud container` does not seem to help:

```
$ gcloud container
Usage: gcloud container [optional flags] <group | command>
  group may be           clusters | operations
  command may be         get-server-config

Deploy and manage clusters of machines for running containers.

flags:
  --zone ZONE, -z ZONE   The compute zone (e.g. us-central1-a) for the cluster

global flags:
  Run `gcloud -h` for a description of flags available to all commands.

command groups:
  clusters               Deploy and teardown Google Container Engine clusters.
  operations             Get and list operations for Google Container Engine
                         clusters.

commands:
  get-server-config      Get Container Engine server config.
```

I also don't want to use `gcloud docker` to list images because this wants to connect to a particular docker daemon that I don't have. Unless there is a way to  tell `gcloud docker` to connect to a remote public docker daemon that can read the private containers pushed to the registry through my project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We just released a new command to list the images in your repository! You can try it out with:

```
gcloud alpha container images list --repository=gcr.io/$MYREPOSITORY
```

If you want to see the specific tags for an image you can use:

```
gcloud alpha container images list-tags gcr.io/$MYREPOSITORY/$MYIMAGE
```

Comment: I can get the first of these to work, but the list-tags command always gives me ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.container.images.list-tags) too few arguments:

Comment: Ah to list tags use `gcloud alpha container images list-tags gcr.io/$project/$image`

Comment: As of the date of this comment you can use beta:
'gcloud beta container images list '

Comment: I understand this is alpha, but just a heads up, on OS X for some reason when i add `--sort-by TIMESTAMP` to the end of the command it drops the most recent container.  I reinstalled GCloud and still the same thing.   For some reason it works on CentOS.  TY for this feature tho!  Would not be able to automate this script without having the tags

Comment: Does anyone know how to get image ids in `list` output? And to sort by time? I am looking for output like `docker images`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by Robert Bailey is good for certain tasks, but might be missing what you specifically want to do. Nonetheless, your comments in reply to his answer are not so much faults of his answer as of your own understanding of what the commands which "fail" actually mean to do.

As far as your second comment,

> Using docker I get the following error (for the reasons mentioned
>   above; I also edited the question): `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

This is a result of the docker daemon not running. Check if it's running via `ps aux | grep docker`. You can refer to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/) to determine how to properly install and run it.

As far as your first comment,

> Using curl I get: `{"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"Failed to read tags for repository '<my_project>/<my_image>'"}]}`. I have to
>   authenticate somehow to access the images in a private registry. I
>   don't want to use docker because that means I have to have a docker
>   daemon available. I only want to see if a container image with a
>   particular version is in the Container Registry. So what I need is an
>   API to the Container Registry in the Google Developer Console.

You wouldn't be able to `curl` the image unless it was public, as mentioned in Robert's latest comment, or unless you somehow provided some great oauth headers during the `curl`'s invocation.

You should use gcloud docker to attempt to list the images in the registry, as you would for other docker registries. The `gcloud container` command group is the wrong one for your desired task. You can see below an output from `gcloud version 96.0.0` (latest as of this comment) for the `docker` command group:

```
$ gcloud docker
Usage: docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND [arg...]
       docker daemon [ --help | ... ]
       docker [ --help | -v | --version ]

A self-sufficient runtime for containers.

Options:

  --config=~/.docker                 Location of client config files
  -D, --debug=false                  Enable debug mode
  --disable-legacy-registry=false    Do not contact legacy registries
  -H, --host=[]                      Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -h, --help=false                   Print usage
  -l, --log-level=info               Set the logging level
  --tls=false                        Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
  --tlscacert=~/.docker/ca.pem       Trust certs signed only by this CA
  --tlscert=~/.docker/cert.pem       Path to TLS certificate file
  --tlskey=~/.docker/key.pem         Path to TLS key file
  --tlsverify=false                  Use TLS and verify the remote
  -v, --version=false                Print version information and quit

Commands:
    attach    Attach to a running container
    build     Build an image from a Dockerfile
    commit    Create a new image from a container's changes
    cp        Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
    create    Create a new container
    diff      Inspect changes on a container's filesystem
    events    Get real time events from the server
    exec      Run a command in a running container
    export    Export a container's filesystem as a tar archive
    history   Show the history of an image
    images    List images
    import    Import the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image
    info      Display system-wide information
    inspect   Return low-level information on a container or image
    kill      Kill a running container
    load      Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN
    login     Register or log in to a Docker registry
    logout    Log out from a Docker registry
    logs      Fetch the logs of a container
    network   Manage Docker networks
    pause     Pause all processes within a container
    port      List port mappings or a specific mapping for the CONTAINER
    ps        List containers
    pull      Pull an image or a repository from a registry
    push      Push an image or a repository to a registry
    rename    Rename a container
    restart   Restart a container
    rm        Remove one or more containers
    rmi       Remove one or more images
    run       Run a command in a new container
    save      Save an image(s) to a tar archive
    search    Search the Docker Hub for images
    start     Start one or more stopped containers
    stats     Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics
    stop      Stop a running container
    tag       Tag an image into a repository
    top       Display the running processes of a container
    unpause   Unpause all processes within a container
    version   Show the Docker version information
    volume    Manage Docker volumes
    wait      Block until a container stops, then print its exit code

Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
```

You should use `gcloud docker search gcr.io/project-id` to check which images are in the repository. `gcloud` has your credentials, so it can talk to the private registry as long as you're authenticated as an appropriate user on the project.

---

Finally, as an added resource: The Cloud Platform docs have a whole article about working with [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/).

Comment: Thanks Nick for the comprehensive answer. On purpose I do not want to use the docker terminal (and play the fool there) because I have to simulate a machine only with `gcloud` installed and without `docker`. This script will be the one coordinating the builds on other instance that have docker. So I think my best solution so far is to `gcloud compute ssh <container_cluster_instance> -C "sudo gcloud docker search ..."`

Answer (score 2):

If you know the project that is hosting the images (e.g. `google-containers`) you can list images with

```
gcloud docker search gcr.io/google_containers
```

For an individual image (e.g. the `pause` image in the `google-containers` project), you can check the versions with

```
curl https://gcr.io/v2/google-containers/pause/tags/list
```

Comment: Using `curl` I get: `{"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"Failed to read tags for repository '<my_project>/<my_image>'"}]}`. I have to authenticate somehow to access the images in a private registry. I don't want to use `docker` because that means I have to have a `docker` daemon available. I only want to see if a container image with a particular version is in the Container Registry. So what I need is an API to the Container Registry in the Google Developer Console.

Comment: Using `docker` I get the following error (for the reasons mentioned above; I also edited the question): `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

Comment: If the images are hosted in a project that you have access to, then you should be able to use the cloud console to view the images and their versions by navigating to https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/images/list. My answer above also works for public images in projects that you don't have direct access to.

Comment: Yes I should be able, but it does not work for us. The list remains empty (see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35314790/454103)

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay If your list is empty there are two things to check: DO NOT use namespaces when pushing images gcr.io, they don't appear in the list.  To see what has been uploaded head to the console and look at Storage and then `artifacts.<projectName>.appspot.com`

Answer (score 2):

I've just found a far simpler way to check for specific images. Once you have authenticated `gcloud`, use it to generate access tokens for reading from your private registry:

```
curl -u "oauth2accesstoken:$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io/v2/<projectName>/<imageName>/tags/list
```

Answer (score 1):

My best solution so far without having a local docker available and without being able to connect to a remote docker (this would still require at least the local docker client but not the local daemon running), is to SSH into a Container Cluster instance that runs `docker` and have my search done there and getting the result in my original script:

```
gcloud compute ssh <container_cluster_instance> -C "sudo gcloud docker search ..."
```

Of course, to avoid all verbose output (like SSH/Terminal welcome messages) I use some arguments to silent the execution a bit:

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-q" "$INSTANCE_NAME" -o LogLevel=quiet -C "sudo gcloud docker search ..."
```