# How do I list images and tags in google container registry

Tags: gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Looking for a way to use the gcloud commandline to get the tags of container engine registry images.

this command

`cloud docker search gcr.io/PROJECT/myimage`

returns

`NAME                  DESCRIPTION   STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
PROJECT/myimage                     0`

but i want to see the tags used so far like the gcloud web console shows.

[image]

the machine I run this command on pulls images from docker hub, tags them, then pushes them to google container engine with `gcloud docker push...`

*I suspect I may be asking how to make the local docker client do commands against both google repo and docker hub repo so I can get `docker images` listings*

****** UPDATE:  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38061253/201911 for this capability in the latest release.

Comment: Possibly a new release that answers your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38061253/201911

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/PROJECT/myimage`
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list-tags

Comment: welp, i regret running this. it ends up listing ALL the tags

Answer (score 5):

Let me tell you hack to relieve your pain:

```bash
ZONE=eu
PROJECT_ID=testproject

PROJECT_URL=gs://${ZONE}.artifacts.${PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com/containers/repositories/library
    
# this generates images list
gsutil ls $PROJECT_URL | sed -e 's#/$##' -e 's#.*/##' 
    
IMAGE_URL=gs://${ZONE}.artifacts.${PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com/containers/repositories/library/${IMAGE_NAME}/

# this generates tags list for specified image
gsutil ls $IMAGE_URL | sed -n '/\/tag_/ { s#.*/tag_##p }'
```

This will serve you in most of the cases.

You will need read permissions to list files in that specific storage bucket in GCE.

Comment: It seems like the structure has changed - we don't have a `containers/repositories` directory - we do have `containers/images`, but it only contains the layer SHA (from what I can gather).

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with `gcloud`. `gcloud docker` is just a wrapper around the `docker` command line tool, which doesn't easily expose the information you'd like for remote repositories.

At some point in the future, `gcloud` may support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

First install the gcloud CLI (`brew install google-cloud-sdk` on MacOS). Then log in (`gcloud auth login`). Then use a command from below to list images/tags.

**Listing images**

`CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=[PROJECT] gcloud container images list` (e.g. `CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT=spiffe-io gcloud container images list`)

**Listing image tags**

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/[PROJECT]/[IMAGE]` (e.g. `gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/spiffe-io/spire-server`)

There is currently no way to search for images across all projects.

See

- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list-tags
- https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list